# Smooth scrolling to specific Co-Ordinates in a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

On the button click I want it to scroll to the desired location. However I cannot workout why it isn't working.

```js
function scrollWin() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 890)
  behavior: "smooth"
}
```

```html
<div class="tp-caption sfb slider tp-resizeme slider"
     style="z-index: 6"
     data-x="center"
     data-hoffset="0"
     data-y="400"
     data-speed="800"
     data-start="1000"
     data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
     data-endspeed="300" data-endeasing="Power1.easeIn"
     data-captionhidden="off">
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-large m-r-10"
          onclick="scrollWin()">
          Check out, what we're about…
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there more html than this? it will not scroll that far if there isnt anywhere to scroll too

Comment: Yes but that’s unnecessary in the fact that it works but is there anything I’d need to add to that specific section of code to make it scroll with smooth behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.scrollTo()` doesn't scroll smoothly by default. You have to do something like [this example provided in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9dc5yfh/).

The theory is to create a loop-alike system to call a method repeatedly to reproduce illustration of smooth scrolling.

Note this is just a very simple ( even stupid ) example code to demonstrate how to do such a job and you shouldn't use this in production mode.

If you need more complex systems, more configuration or more control over time, speed and type of animation, you should use something like [Scrull](https://github.com/mrReiha/scrull) or any smooth scroll library out there.